# IndoorAtlas : How many times is sufficient/necessary for mapping coverage in the same path?

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system

I have a question and problem in mapping data coverage - **How many times is sufficient or necessary for mapping coverage in the same path ?**
for example, if I have 2 waypoint distance by 10m. assume A and B. Is it necessary to repeat collecting data in the same path as A->B ,B->A in many time. 
Mapping coverage, this depend on times of collecting path ?

Thank you in advance for your kind support

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not necessary as long as you are satisfied with the positioning accuracy.

Comment: Thanks @Neel0507 I have found although the mapping coverage is really good but positioning on the map is still incorrect. The dot jump over the actual location especially in IOS device. I observed that positioning will be perfect probably depending on collecting data method i.e number of paths in one route or direction of mapping. Have you ever seen this problem ?

Comment: I had the same issue during my project and I came to realise two things. The first thing which is crucial for the positioning is how accurately you have aligned your floor plan on the web application. The second thing is to make sure the test paths shows more green area than yellow or red area (I hope it still shows the same as I did my project 18 months ago). For some further help you can read my project blog here: https://myprofblogs.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/how-indoor-positioning-system-worked.html.